# How to display stream video frames in Qt app using Gstreamer receive from UDP socket

Tags: qt, gstreamer, udpclient

I would like to use Qt Multimedia to display a video stream.
I have run

```
@server: $gst-launch-1.0 -v videotestsrc  pattern=ball ! video/x-raw,width=1280,height=720 ! jpegenc ! rtpjpegpay ! udpsink name=sink host=localhost port=34400 sync=false async=false         

@client: $gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=34400 caps="application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)JPEG, payload=(int)26" ! rtpjpegdepay ! jpegdec ! filesink location=a.mp4
```

Its working fine.
now I want to server command on one terminal and Qt app should play the part of client so it will play video.
I have tried one app but its not working.

**main.cpp**:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMediaPlayer>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QVideoWidget>
#include <QBoxLayout>
#include <QProcess>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QWidget *window = new QWidget;
    QVideoWidget *videoWidget = new QVideoWidget;
    QBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;
    QMediaPlayer *player = new QMediaPlayer;
    QProcess *process = new QProcess;

    layout->addWidget(videoWidget);
    window->setLayout(layout);
    window->show();
    player->setVideoOutput(videoWidget);
    QString program = "gst-launch-1.0";
    QStringList arguments;
    arguments << "udpsrc" << "port=34400" << "caps=application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, 
    clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)JPEG, payload=(int)26" << "!" << "rtpjpegdepay" 
    << "!" << "jpegdec" << "!" << "filesink location=a.mp4" ;
    
    process->setReadChannel(QProcess::StandardError);
    process->start(program, arguments);

    while (!process->waitForReadyRead()) {}

    player->setMedia(QMediaContent(), process);
    player->play();

    return a.exec();
```

**project.pro**:

```
QT       += core gui multimedia multimediawidgets

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = video_play_file
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        dialog.cpp

HEADERS  += dialog.h

FORMS    += dialog.ui
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Qt 5.12.2, you can pass GStreamer pipelines to QMediaPlayer::setMedia() if the GStreamer backend is used. In your case the code for setMedia() should look something like this (untested):

```
...
player->setMedia(QUrl("gst-pipeline: udpsrc port=34400 caps=\"application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)JPEG, payload=(int)26\" ! rtpjpegdepay ! jpegdec ! videoconvert ! xvimagesink name=\"qtvideosink\""));
...
```

Take a look at the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediaplayer.html#setMedia)  for more information.

Comment: Thanks for u r prompt help. i have first tested ```player = new QMediaPlayer;
    player->setMedia(QUrl("gst-pipeline: videotestsrc ! autovideosink"));
    player->play();


    qDebug() <<player->state();

    return a.exec();

}``` but throwing Error: "No URI handler implemented for \"gst-pipeline\"."

Comment: What version of Qt do you use? At least Qt 5.12.2 is required. Is your Qt client app running on Linux? The Gstreamer backend of Qt Multimedia is only supported on Linux.

Comment: Yes right ,because of Qt version i am using (QT Creator 3.5.1). so i have stared to build a new QT version Qt 5.12.0 .

Comment: could you please suggest me Qt version which support Gstreamer pipeline and links to setup  that QT  on linux facing some issue with version 5.12.0.

Comment: The documentation states that at least Qt 5.12.2 is required. Install the latest Ubuntu LTS version (20.04, Focal Fossa). It includes libqt5multimedia5 version 5.12.8. Look here for instructions: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop

Comment: I think that is out of scope of your original questions. Start a new question for such instructions.

Comment: Yes right ptr. I have setup Qt 5.12.0 on ubuntu 16.06 LTS.

Comment: Hello ptr, I have setup Qt 5.12.9 on ubuntu and tried above application with u r comment. i am able to build and run but Qt widget showing nothing on screen. could you please suggest ?

Comment: Hello ptr. i have edited my application but still facing same issue.